# Why adapter function changing my num array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I want to push function such that it doesn't change my `num` array, but it's changing it, why? `nums` parameter in this function is the reference to `num` array

```js
var num = []

function push(nums) {
  var orig = nums.map(x => x)
  var newNum = pushed()
  nums = orig
  return newNum
}

function pushed() {
  num.push(1)
  return num
}

console.log("new", push(num))
console.log("old", num)
```

Comment: _"why?"_ -> `num.push(1)`

Comment: Because `num.push(1)`. The copy created pre–push is not saved so it vanishes as garbage when the *push* function ends. Perhaps `num = orig` (remove the "s").

Answer (score 0):

You are making `nums` to reference `orig` but it won't make `num` to reference it.

changing it to `num = orig` will make it work.

```js
var num = []

function push(nums) {
  var orig = nums.map(x => x)
  var newNum = pushed()
  num = orig
  return newNum
}

function pushed() {
  num.push(1)
  return num
}

console.log("new", push(num))
console.log("old", num)
```

Comment: I want num array to remain as it is (empty) but pushed function is changing it, so i made a wrapper adapter function, but the concept of how dynamic allocation of variable works in js, so i remember it now and changing the nums reference will only changes it's reference but not num array's.